# Calling GetType() or typeof on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook returns System.ComObject

Tags: c#, outlook, com, interop, automapper

I have this code:

```
 public MeetingDto MapFrom(AppointmentItem input)
    {
        InitMaps();

        var result = (MeetingDto)Mapper.Map(input, typeof(AppointmentItem), typeof(MeetingDto));

        return result;
    }
```

and the issue is when I try to call `typeof(AppointmentItem` or `input.GetType()` it returns the type **System.__ComObject** which makes the Automapper sad.

Is there a way how to pass to automapper the correct type?

Comment: You can get a type from it's name using [`Type.GetType(name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) but I still wouldn't expect AutoMapper to work. How are you declaring the mapping?

Comment: here it is: `public static object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType);`